# Disable custom scaling factor

Tags: windows-10, scaling

Each time I restart my Windows 10 I have applied custom scaling factor. In order to get scaling I need I should always press `Turn off custom scaling and sign out`. How to disable custom custom scaling forever?

[image]

UPD.

Advanced scaling settings contains custom scaling setting - 100. If I enter something less than 100 or delete value `Apply` button remains disabled. In case I enter something bigger than 100 `Apply` button is enabled.

[image]

Comment: If you click on `Advanced scaling settings` is there something in the `Custom Scaling` text box? If there is, blank the field and click `Apply`. Let us know what you find.

Comment: Currently value of 100 is set in custom scaling.  If I enter something less than 100 or delete value Apply button remains disabled. More details in updated question body

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like for me: [image: screenshot]

Maybe you missed it because you went straight into Advanced Settings.